# Is a 'block' and a 'page' the same thing in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, terminology

I've seen many blogs and videos talking about Postgres 'blocks'. Are these the same as 'pages' in other database management system implementations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about the 8kB subdivisions of physical table storage, then yes.

These are usually called "pages" in Postgres as well, and that is the terminology used in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html).